# Broken Fastlane installation / mix Ruby versions

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I'm quite new to ruby, gems and such but got fastlane installed and setup quite nicely. I then ran into this issue for deliver:

https://github.com/fastlane/deliver/issues/349

I tried to update to the lastest version of fastlane but then ran into this issue:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/567

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/sigh
```

I tried the

```
gem update -n /usr/local/bin fastlane
gem update -n /usr/local/bin sigh
gem update -n /usr/local/bin deliver
```

without success. These only led me to this error:

```
Unable to activate deliver-1.9.0, because plist-3.2.0 conflicts with plist (~> 3.1.0 ...
```

I also tried

```
sudo su
sudo gem install fastlane --verbose
exit
```

Without success. After that I tried to install bundler, a new ruby version and do cleanups and reinstalls. No success. Now everything seems to be in a bad state and trying to install fastlane with the normal command

```
install fastlane --verbose
```

leads to

```
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Same command with sudo gives:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/snapshot-1.6.0/lib/snapshot/version.rb
ERROR: While executing gem ... (TypeError)
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

What to do??

`ruby -v` gives me `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]` and `echo $PATH` gives me `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by installing

https://rvm.io/

My command history:

```
brew install gnupg gnupg2
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source /Users/xxx/.rvm/scripts/rvm
gem install fastlane --verbose
xcode-select --install
gem cleanup
gem update -p
rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local
gem install fastlane --verbose
```

One issue along the way:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/745

Answer (score 0):

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin fastlane`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it